# Prove Fubini's Theorem for non-negative functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The objective is to prove the complete Fubini's Theorem

$$\int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y)dy\right)dx=\int_\mathbb{R^2}f$$

where $f : \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue absolutely integrable function.

Since the Lebesgue integration is defined by positive and negative parts (i.e. $\int_\Omega f=\int_\Omega f^+ - \int_\Omega f^-$ where $f^+=max(f,0)$ and $f^-=-min(f,0)$). It suffices to prove the theorem for non-negative functions, and use the linearity of non-negative integration to prove the general case.

Next, it suffices to prove the theorem for non-negatively supported functions $f$ on $[-N,N]\times[-N,N]$ for some positive integer N then take suprema

$$f=\sup_{N>0}f1_{[-N,N]\times[-N,N]}$$

and apply the monotone convergence theorem ($\sup\int f_n=\int\sup f_n$ where $f_n(x)$ is monotone increasing on $n$ for any fixed $x$).

Similarly, the integration of non-negative functions is defined as

$$\int_\Omega f=\sup\left\{\int_\Omega s:\text{s is a simple function and minorizes f}\right\}$$

I think I could use the monotone convergence theorem again. But it applies to sequences of functions, not sets of functions. If I were to construct a sequence, the subscript would depend on $x$ and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Why don't you read the proof from a book. If you have difficulty with any step in the proof you can seek help here.